# Android custom View (Свой View на Android)

Tags: java, android, listview, canvas

Есть у меня один перегруженный Layout для списка чатов. Там и автарка, время, текст, имя/название, статус сообщений, и куча мелочей, типо иконки онлайн, иконки чата, и статуса сообщения. 
Подумал я что это очень плохо, и решил нарисовать свой View для оптимизации (на старых устройства прокрутка подтормаживает). В общих чертах получается, но есть некоторые вопросы.

1. CustomView в BaseAdapter ведет себя как то странно. При прокрутке элементы пропадают, а когда прокрутка останавливается, они появляются, и перерисовываются по раз 10. Как это исправить?
2. В Canvas есть какие то странные отступы, например если не установить canvas.translate то рисунок заезжает вверх, и в лево. Я ставлю отступы, и вроде нормально, НО, будут ли такие самые отступы, размеры, и тому подобное, на других расширениях экрана? (Переводжу dp в px, и устаналиваю их как размер отступа, холста, и т. п.)
3. Аватарки юзеров загружаются в другом потоке, после загрузки их нужно показать в моем CustomView. Как правильно "нарисовать" аватарку после загрузки? Перерисовывать весь View ?
4. Есть ли какие то подобные гайды, с примерами, для прорисовки своих View? Кроме официальных андроидовских.

На скрине изображено, как сейчас отображаются чаты, с моим перегруженным Layout

[image: Скрин списка диалогов]

Прощу пояснить все понятно, желательно с примерами, или ссылками на подобные вещи.

Спасибо.

Comment: Добавьте свой код, а то много вариантов

Comment: Его почти нету, там только текст, и круг placeholder для аватарки

Comment: В адаптере использовать патттерн ViewHolder, тогда проблема с перерисовкой пропадет. А если проблема конкретно с изображениями, то их необходимо кэшировать, плюс, очищать imageView перед тем как засунуть туда новое изображение

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте по этому примеру

***[это из сайта](http://javapapers.com/android/android-listview-custom-layout-tutorial/)***

ListView Layout XML - **Это список - контейнер**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
     />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Вот это самое главное - тут вы меняте элемент списка по вашему рассмотрению**

Custom Layout for Row in ListView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fruitImg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fruitName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fruitImg"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="Cherry"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/calories"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

ListAdapter - для обработки

```
package com.javapapers.android.listviewcustomlayout.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FruitArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Fruit> {
    private static final String TAG = "FruitArrayAdapter";
    private List<Fruit> fruitList = new ArrayList<Fruit>();

    static class FruitViewHolder {
        ImageView fruitImg;
        TextView fruitName;
        TextView calories;
    }

    public FruitArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Fruit object) {
        fruitList.add(object);
        super.add(object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fruitList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fruit getItem(int index) {
        return this.fruitList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        FruitViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row_layout, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new FruitViewHolder();
            viewHolder.fruitImg = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.fruitImg);
            viewHolder.fruitName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.fruitName);
            viewHolder.calories = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.calories);
            row.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (FruitViewHolder)row.getTag();
        }
        Fruit fruit = getItem(position);
        viewHolder.fruitImg.setImageResource(fruit.getFruitImg());
        viewHolder.fruitName.setText(fruit.getFruitName());
        viewHolder.calories.setText(fruit.getCalories());
        return row;
    }

    public Bitmap decodeToBitmap(byte[] decodedByte) {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
    }
}
```

ListView Activity - c примерами

```
package com.javapapers.android.listviewcustomlayout.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListViewActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "ListViewActivity";

    private FruitArrayAdapter fruitArrayAdapter;
    private ListView listView;

    private static int colorIndex;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_layout);
        colorIndex = 0;
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        fruitArrayAdapter = new FruitArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.listview_row_layout);
        listView.setAdapter(fruitArrayAdapter);

        List<String[]> fruitList = readData();
        for(String[] fruitData:fruitList ) {
            String fruitImg = fruitData[0];
            String fruitName = fruitData[1];
            String calories = fruitData[2];
            int fruitImgResId = getResources().getIdentifier(fruitImg, "drawable", "com.javapapers.android.listviewcustomlayout.app");

            Fruit fruit = new Fruit(fruitImgResId,fruitName,calories);
            fruitArrayAdapter.add(fruit);
        }
    }

    public List<String[]> readData(){
        List<String[]> resultList = new ArrayList<String[]>();

        String[] fruit7 = new String[3];
        fruit7[0] = "orange";
        fruit7[1] = "Orange";
        fruit7[2] = "47 Calories";
        resultList.add(fruit7);

        String[] fruit1 = new String[3];
        fruit1[0] = "cherry";
        fruit1[1] = "Cherry";
        fruit1[2] = "50 Calories";
        resultList.add(fruit1);


        String[] fruit3 = new String[3];
        fruit3[0] = "banana";
        fruit3[1] = "Banana";
        fruit3[2] = "89 Calories";
        resultList.add(fruit3);

        String[] fruit4 = new String[3];
        fruit4[0] = "apple";
        fruit4[1] = "Apple";
        fruit4[2] = "52 Calories";
        resultList.add(fruit4);

        String[] fruit10 = new String[3];
        fruit10[0] = "kiwi";
        fruit10[1] = "Kiwi";
        fruit10[2] = "61 Calories";
        resultList.add(fruit10);

        String[] fruit5 = new String[3];
        fruit5[0] = "pear";
        fruit5[1] = "Pear";
        fruit5[2] = "57 Calories";
        resultList.add(fruit5);


        String[] fruit2 = new String[3];
        fruit2[0] = "strawberry";
        fruit2[1] = "Strawberry";
        fruit2[2] = "33 Calories";
        resultList.add(fruit2);

        String[] fruit6 = new String[3];
        fruit6[0] = "lemon";
        fruit6[1] = "Lemon";
        fruit6[2] = "29 Calories";
        resultList.add(fruit6);

        String[] fruit8 = new String[3];
        fruit8[0] = "peach";
        fruit8[1] = "Peach";
        fruit8[2] = "39 Calories";
        resultList.add(fruit8);

        String[] fruit9 = new String[3];
        fruit9[0] = "apricot";
        fruit9[1] = "Apricot";
        fruit9[2] = "48 Calories";
        resultList.add(fruit9);

        String[] fruit11 = new String[3];
        fruit11[0] = "mango";
        fruit11[1] = "Mango";
        fruit11[2] = "60 Calories";
        resultList.add(fruit11);

        return  resultList;
    }

}
```

Comment: Вы меня абсолютно не поняли

Comment: можете тогда хоть примерами обяснить?

Comment: Рисование своего View средствами Canvas

Comment: сорри, значит я не правильно понял.

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле, достаточно использовать RecyclerView и оптимально сверстать данный элемент списка. Под "оптимально" я имею ввиду исключить вложенность и допустим сверстать все с помощью RelativeLayout.